# How use 'fcntl' on Windows with and MinGW?

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm trying to port a TCP application (specifically [tcpsockets](https://github.com/vichargrave/tcpsockets)), however im getting this error:

> error: 'fcntl' was not declared in this scope

I already wrote those includes

```
#ifdef WIN32
#define _WIN32_WINNT  0x0600 //enable

#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

typedef int socklen_t;
void close(int socket){closesocket(socket);}

#else

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#endif
```

Which solved most part of the references, however `fcntl` was not found.
How can I find a proper reference to it? Or naybe is there another windows method that could replace it?

Comment: Maybe you could show us what the fcntl is being used for so we can help figure out what the equivalent windows thing is.

Comment: Have you checked out the [asio](https://think-async.com/Asio/) library? It's cross-platform and can be used either as part of Boost or as a stand-alone library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fcntl()` does not exist on Windows.  For sockets, the equivalent function is [`ioctlsocket()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738573.aspx).  However, file controls on sockets in Linux are very different than in Windows, so not all of the `fcntl()` commands you are using may port to Windows at all, or they may require different APIs.

Comment: Why is there a `fcntl.h` header in mingw if it doesn't have the function

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you are trying to use native sockets. But if there's no real reason, have a look at [`QTcpSocket`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpsocket.html) instead. It's the Qt class for sockets and works on all platforms.

Comment: Wouldn't this require adding Qt to the poster's program as a dependency?  That's a pretty significant addition in program-size and complexity, too much to justify if the only benefit is that the programmer won't have to figure out how to make `fcntl()` work.